# How to submit a POST using <a href=""> tag?

Tags: php, html, http, post, href

I realize we need forms to submit a POST or perhaps with the help of a button. However, how do we do it using  tags? Example code:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("pictures.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    while(!feof($myfile)){
      $pic_name= fgets($myfile);
      echo '<div class="grid-item">';
      echo '<a href="redirect.php"><img src="' . $pic_name . '.jpg"></a>';
      echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

I'm trying use PHP to read a text file for a number of variables (names of each picture that I've saved). From the text file, this PHP will then convert the variables into multiple images (for each variables). Upon clicking the image, this should send the name of the picture to the next PHP site so the picture is displayed in full screen. Assume this is some kind of photo library thing that I'm trying to do. I've tried searching elsewhere but couldn't get an answer for this.

Comment: *"How to submit a POST using <a href="* - can't.

Comment: Use a `<form` not an `<a`.. might be able to write JS to send POST from `a` button but it's considerably more work.

Comment: I know it can be done but I would not like to use form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use get method instead for sending data for eg.
"form.php?name1=value1&name2=value2"

```html
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("pictures.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    while(!feof($myfile)){
      $pic_name= fgets($myfile);
      echo '<div class="grid-item">';
      echo '<a href="redirect.php/?pic_name=".$pic_name.><img src="' . $pic_name . '.jpg"></a>';
      echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Raja. This is the answer I've been finding for. Although for anyone else that might come by the same issue, I would like to correct the code a little bit for an easier copy paste:

echo '<a href="redirect.php/?pic_name="' . $pic_name . '><img src="' . $pic_name . '.jpg"></a>';